# Application migration fromm Mongo to MySql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mean-stack

our appliction is developed in Angular 9, Mangoose with Mongo database. We would like to see application getting worked for MySql database as well. Are there any practices to follow in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Databases contain data in different formats.

You will have to go through the following steps:

1. Isolate CRUD-operations with MongoDB (e.g. mongoUsersRepository, mongoOrdersRepository etc.).
2. Prepare MySQL table structure
3. Create repositories for CRUD-operations with MySQL (e.g. mysqlUsersRepository, mysqlOrdersRepository etc.).
4. Transfer data from Mongo repositories to Mysql repositories.
5. Replace Mongo repositories on Mysql repositories.